# Django и OpenID

Tags: openid, django

Нужно мне в одном проекте прикрутить регистрацию через OpenID и соц. сети. Погуглил, информацию нашел, но как-то все слишком размыто и поверхностно. Может кто-то уже занимался такой проблемой? Посоветуйте действенный способ, приложение. В идеале - было бы классно увидеть исходник реализации, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недавно тоже прикручивал openId и так же как и вы столкнулся с множеством приложений без каких либо внятных примеров их использования. К счастью наткнулся на [django-publicauth](https://bitbucket.org/offline/django-publicauth/wiki/Home) от автора pyplanet.org. Вот [тут](http://pyplanet.org/static/auth_example2.tar.gz) **чистый проект с примером** авторизации и регистрации, а [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/django/91568/) пост автора про авторизацию и регистрацию "вконтакте". Вконтакте регистрация у меня почему то не заработала на боевом сервере, но на тестовом работала. Все остальное слепленное из примера заработало прекрасно.

Answer (score 1):

Есть Django Social Auth (http://social.matiasaguirre.net/), который позволяет вставить аутентификацию с помощью аккаунтов в соц. сетях и через OpenID.